# Apache mod-proxy ProxyErrorOverride for specific URL patterns

Tags: apache, mod-proxy

I am using Apache 2.2 with mod-proxy and I have configured it with several ProxyPass statements to proxy from remote URL to local URL.  I need to have custom error documents returned from Apache for these proxied URLs so I set "ProxyErrorOverride On" in my mod-proxy configuration along with some ErrorDocument directives (with local URL path) to return custom error pages for a few HTTP status codes of interest.  However, when a status code is returned for which I have NOT created an ErrorDocument directive for, Apache replaces the response body with a default error page instead of leaving the original response body intact.  This won't work with the application.  So I really have 2 questions:

1) Is it possible to configure Apache to leave the original response body intact for a particular status code if I don't have an ErrorDocument override defined for it?

2) Is it possible to have the ProxyErrorOverride directive only apply to some of the URLs in my ProxyPass statements?

Comment: Afraid the answer is: No and No.  If the directive could be limited to a location, directory, or set of URL's, then there would be something in the "Context" section, of the man page: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxyerroroverride

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As arober11 pointed out in the comment above:

> Afraid the answer is: No and No. If the directive could be limited to
>   a location, directory, or set of URL's, then there would be something
>   in the "Context" section, of the man page:
>   httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxyerroroverride

on the other hand: you can always add it to mod_proxy.c yourself.

Answer (score 2):

**For question 2:**
Definitely doable. Using internal redirects to either new host or port this is possible. Brief outline using hosts (add noErrorOverrideUrl,doErrorOverrideUrl in DNS or /etc/hosts of apache-machine):

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
<VirtualHost *:80>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteRule ^(/noErrorOverrideUrl/.*) http://noErrorOverrideUrl$1 [L,P]
   RewriteRule ^(/doErrorOverrideUrl/.*) http://doErrorOverrideUrl$1 [L,P]          
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName noErrorOverrideUrl
   ProxyErrorOverride Off
   ProxyPass ...
   ...
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:80>
   ServerName doErrorOverrideUrl
   ProxyErrorOverride On
   ProxyPass ...
   ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Brief outline using ports:

```
Listen 80
Listen 81
Listen 82
<VirtualHost *:80>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteRule ^(/noErrorOverrideUrl/.*) http://server:81$1 [L,P]
   RewriteRule ^(/doErrorOverrideUrl/.*) http://server:82$1 [L,P]
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:81>
   ProxyErrorOverride Off
   ProxyPass ...
   ...
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:82>
   ProxyErrorOverride On
   ProxyPass ...
   ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can upgrade apache and use the If sentence avaible on 2.4+

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ...
  <If "%{REQUEST_URI} =~ m#^\/QA(.*)$#">
      ProxyErrorOverride Off
  </If>
  ..
</VirtualHost>
```

[Documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/expr.html)