# How to perform Apache redirect upon server code response to client

Tags: apache, redirect

I'm having issues trying to perform a redirect when code response is 5xx. 
Any thoughts on how I achieve that within an Apache conf file?

ex) Logic

If the host is "abc.com" and code response from the server is 501
then perform a 301 redirect to xyz.com

I haven't found a way to intercept response coming from Tomcat via AJP protocol as well and perform any URL or header re-writing.

Help help is much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Found some useful links: 

https://www.xtivia.com/custom-error-pages-liferay-dxp/

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7588229/apache-mod-proxy-proxyerroroverride-for-specific-url-patterns

Comment: Pretty much, I'll have to move all the custom error pages from Tomcat application into static files on the Apache web server, use the "ProxyErrorOverride On"
feature and have an "ErrorDocument" for each status code errors. It's all or nothing, and you can hand select some to come from either Tomcat or Apache. 

If anyone has any other slick ideas, let me know. 

Thanks.